# Explicitly give the elements and structure of the group $S_n/A_n$, $n ≥ 5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Explicitly give the elements and structure of the group $S_n/A_n$, $n ≥ 5$. 
I know that for $n≥5$, the alternating group $A_n$ is simple. Also for $n ≥ 5$, $S_n$ is an almost simple group, as it lies between the simple group $A_n$ and its group of automorphisms. I do not know how to "explicitly" write the structure of the group.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of any quotient group $G/N$ are the cosets $gN$ (for different $g\in G$). How many cosets are there in your case? Write them all down, and you have explicitly given the elements.

Explicitly writing the structure means writing down a full multiplication table, or in some other, equivalent manner describe exactly how the group operation works. Since you have listed all the elements already, that shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For any two odd permutations $\sigma,\sigma'\in S_n$, we have $\sigma^{-1}\sigma'\in A_n$.